# “使用者不得使用多數的帳戶在討論區中發言”: should 多數 be replaced with 多個?

Tags: word-choice

On [this page](https://ctext.org/faq/forum-rules/zh), I read 使用者不得使用**多數**的帳戶在討論區中發言, which I think 多數 is a mistake and it should be 多個.

> 使用者不得使用**多數**的帳戶在討論區中發言。使用者雖然不必使用自己的真實姓名登記，但不得有意使用他人的姓名登記。

Update: Seems that it is really a mistake since in [the English version](https://ctext.org/faq/forum-rules/) the term used is `multiple'.

> Users may not post messages from multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, 多數帳戶 (majority/ most account) is a wrong choice of word. It should be 多個帳戶 (multiple accounts) or 多於一個帳戶 (more than one account) in this context